# Visa-free entry to the UK refused due to frequent visit and overstay! Help with visitor visa

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, overstaying, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry, deportation

Please excuse my poor English.

I'm Malaysian, 24 years old. I was refused entry in the UK on March 23, 2018 due to frequent and successive visits to the UK in 2017. The entry clearance officer advised me to apply for a visa before my next visit to the UK. I had a big cross over the entry stamp on my passport.

On March 23, it was my fifth trip to the UK. The main purpose was to visit my partner, sightseeing in the UK and travel to other European countries.

I came to the UK on March 23, 2017 and left to Malaysia on July 28, 2017. During this period, I’ve made several trips to Europe: Prague, Paris, Rome, Vatican City, Florence, Venice, Cinque Terre and Milan, because we love travelling. After I returned to my home country on July 28, I travelled to the UK again on October 4 and left on December 13, 2017. During this period, I’ve travelled around the UK for sightseeing and to Amsterdam as well. After I returned home on December 13, I travelled to the UK again in January and returned on February 9 this year. During this period I travelled to Iceland with my partner.

I was never stopped by the UK Border because my partner accompanied me all the time. Unfortunately he failed to accompany me this time. We had no good knowledge about Immigration rules until this thing happened. From March 23, 2017 to March 23, 2018, I spent 212 days in the UK.

I'm not financial independent because I've been unemployed since the day I graduated in November 2016. I have savings, 4,400 pounds, in my account. My father covers all my expenses when I'm in Malaysia. My partner sponsored and accommodated me all the time when I was in the UK. He's a non-EU citizen on a full-time student visa. His mother is willing to sponsor me as well, because she used to encourage us to travel more when we’re young.

I plan to travel end of April and return on June 28. I’m able to show evidence of supporting documents as my building society book; my housing to prove I’m living the current address; original bank statements, including my partner's, his mother's, and my father's; a sponsor letter from my father and my partner's mother; an invitation and sponsor letter from my partner; a certified copy of my partner’s birth certificate, passport, BRP card and student ID; travel itinerary (I plan to travel to Budapest, Athens, Mykonos, Santorini, Spain and Portugal); original tenancy; return flight ticket.

1. Do I have to prove the relationship between my partner and I?
2. What are the consequences if I overstayed in the UK for 32 days?
3. Do I need a lawyer to represent me to apply for a Standard Visitor Visa as I was refused entry to the UK?
4. Do I have to provide a letter from my partner's landlord in order to prove I'm allowed to stay in the place?
5. How can I show strong ties to my country as I'm unemployed now? For example, a job offer or study offer? I can look for a job or continue my Master's because I’m desperate to travel to the UK and other European countries as I listed above.

PS: We’re not planning to settle down in the UK.

Comment: From you narrative, it seems that you did not actually overstay your visa, just that they assume that you are making the UK your primary home (which is not allowed on a tourist visa) due to your frequent & long visits.

Comment: Haven’t counted the days precisely (missing a few details to do so anyway), but 212 days in the UK in the last year does not seem consistent with the dates provided if you take out all the time you say you spent outside of the UK. But that seems hardly relevant, you have spent a lot of time in the UK, by your own admission you have a boyfriend there, and since you don’t have a job at home, there’s nothing much to show you are going to go back there, quite the opposite. You are clearly out of the bounds of a standard visitor visa.

Comment: You should consult a lawyer just because this will be less stressful than trying to complete the application by yourself.

Comment: I would advise you not to bother to apply for some time. The chances of a refusal are astronomically high with your profile and history.